# Никак не получается реализовать функцию стирания данных в калькуляторе js

Tags: javascript, html

```
HTML:
<form name="form">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="text">
        </form>
    <button onclick="clean()">C</button>
    JS:
    function clean() {
        document.form.text.value = '';
    }
```

```js
function clean() {
  document.form.text.value = '';
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="text" value="test">
</form>
<button onclick="clean()">C</button>
```

Вроде бы все должно работать, но данные ни в какую не стираются.

Comment: Странно, у меня все работает: данные стираются

Comment: Либо js подгружаешь неправильно, либо `e.preventDefault()`